I use the vueup/vue-quill package in vue3 and I get the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop')
I am using Vue 3 and the package vueup/vue-quill for rich text editing. In the template, I do this:
<QuillEditor :toolbar="toolbar" :modules="modules"/>

Here is the script code:

import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill';

import 'quill/dist/quill.core.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
import 'quill-better-table/dist/quill-better-table.css';
import QuillBetterTable from 'quill-better-table';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    QuillEditor,
  },

  setup() {
    const toolbar = [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
      ['link', 'image'],
      [{ 'table': true }], // Table button
      ['clean'],
    ];

    const modules = [
      {
        name: 'blotFormatter',
        module: BlotFormatter,
        options: {/* options */}
      },
      {
        name: 'better-table',
        module: QuillBetterTable,
        options: {
          operationMenu: {
            items: {
              unmergeCells: {
                text: 'Unmerge cells'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ];

    return {
      modules, toolbar
    }
  }
});

As soon as the 'better-table' module is added, I get this error:
quill-better-table.js?v=ed9bacc4:2583 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pop')
at new quill_better_table_BetterTable
I've been struggling with this issue for a week.
I tried other packages without any solution, yet I followed the documentation of vue-quill.

Not sure if this is the problem, but looking at the package.json, quill-better-table requires quill 2, but vueup/vue-quill does not support v2 and seems to be dead. There is a github issue about it, as proposed I switched to vue-quilly, which works nicely (though I have not used it with better-table).
